# Designing a RESTful API

Tags: django, rest, http-headers

I am designing a REST API as a backend service for Android app of a startup. The startup currently has a web version of their service with around 10k users. I have a couple of doubts regarding the design of web APIs:

1. **How do I make my API secure?**

I want only the Android client to access the API and no one else. One way would be to send an encrypted token from the front-end and decrypt on the back-end. Is there any other way? Also, how should I implement it?

2. **How to make my API fast and efficient?**

There is a particular endpoint which is accessed very frequently. The information on that endpoint does not change much though. Therefore requests that are made within a short time frame are most likely to return the same response. How do I make response of such requests faster? Would `ETag` and `Last-Modified` do the job?

3. **Should I trust data from my client?**

Currently when I receive a request with some parameter the only check I perform on the request is to check if the parameter is `null` or not. For eg. If a request has `mobile` as a parameter I only check if the `mobile` parameter is present in the request. I do not perform other checks like checking the if length of `mobile` is less than 10 then throw an exception.

**EDIT:**
Anyone who feels that the question is 'too broad', please leave a comment so that I can edit the question and add any necessary details.

Comment: The question is broad, but here's some feedback. 1. "secure" can [mean many things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Definitions). Consider what resources you are protecting, and how they are accessed. For the specific task you mentioned, maybe try establishing sessions over HTTPS and passing a token, but this can be a whole question on its own. 2. There are may factors that impact the latency of an API request. Try using a profiling tool to determine where most time is spent. Caching is a good option, but consider where it is done (database?, session?, app?). 3. No, never.

Comment: @pieman72 1. By secure I meant only the android client could access the API. I think a token would work fine. 2. Could you suggest a good profiling tool to measure API performance? 3. Yes, I shouldn't the trust the data from client and implement all the necessary checks.

Comment: You'll need different tools depending on your application stack, but it looks like you're using Django, so maybe this: [https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a startup and I had pretty much the same problems to resolve. I think the only difference is in the first question because I decided to limit the API access only to authenticated users. However, here is how I solved my problems:

**1. How to make my API secure?**

As I wrote, I limited the API access only to authenticated users. I'm using a token-based authentication with my own REST registration/authentication API endpoints based on the following packages:

- [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
- [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth)

If you'd like to use this solution I suggest you to give a look also at [django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

**2. How to make my API fast and efficient?**

If you have "requests that are made within a short time frame and that are most likely to return the same response", I suggest you to cache this response, something like this (simplest version):

```
if response_in_cache and time_passed < max_time_frame:
    return response_in_cache
else:
    generate response
    save response in the cache (for next time)
    return response
```

You can also track your api performances using New Relic.

**3. Should I trust data from my client?**

Absolutely not! Try to use [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for your RESTful API. It provides a class called *Serializer* which gives you a powerful way to control the input/output of your requests/responses. Here an example:

**Your serializer**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

**Validation**

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(data={'email': 'foobar', 'content': 'baz'})
serializer.is_valid()
# False
serializer.errors
# {'email': [u'Enter a valid e-mail address.'], 'created': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Give a look to the [serializer documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).